# Show DataTable in a TreeView control

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable  TblTreeView which has four columns

ParentID(pk) | ParentName| LeftChildID | RightChildID

and I want to display all data in tree view ;

like so

ParentName

|

|_LeftChildID

|

|_RightChildID

I was using

```
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblTreeView", SqlCon);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    TreeView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
    TreeView1.DataBind();
```

Then an error occurred:-  HierarchicalDataBoundControl only accepts data sources that implement IHierarchicalDataSource or IHierarchicalEnumerable.
Please give me the code to do this;
Thank you Sir/Madam

Comment: If names are not PK, how do you find left/right child? Shouldn't it be LeftChildID and RightChildID?

Comment: Ok Sir but now i got same error as above :-  HierarchicalDataBoundControl only accepts data sources that implement IHierarchicalDataSource or IHierarchicalEnumerable

Comment: What technology do you use? WPF, WinForm, ...?

Comment: asp.net Web form(.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

These samples may be a guide 
[Implementing IHierarchy Support Into Your Custom Collections](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19639/Implementing-IHierarchy-Support-Into-Your-Custom-C) 
[A Hierarchical Repeater and Accessories to Match](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14938/A-Hierarchical-Repeater-and-Accessories-to-Match)

Answer (score 1):

I see this Article is very great to bind data from Dataset.

[Binding the ASP.NET TreeView to a DataSet or an ObjectDataSource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25753/Binding-the-ASP-NET-TreeView-to-a-DataSet-or-an-Ob)

I implemented this code like the following..

```
    private void GenerateCoaTree()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dcAccountingDataContext dc = new dcAccountingDataContext();
        DataTable dt = dc.usp_RPT_ChartOfAccount_Select(null, CompanyID).CopyToDataTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
       // The second parmeter for the ID of the element and the third parameter is the ID of the parent element in the tree.
        TreeViewCoa.DataSource = new HierarchicalDataSet(ds, "AccountID", "COA_ID");
        TreeViewCoa.DataBind();
    }
```

and I invoked this method inside Page_Load page for binding the TreeView control when page loaded for the first time.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GenerateCoaTree();
    }
}

<asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewCoa" runat="server">
    <DataBindings>
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="System.Data.DataRowView" 
            TextField="COADescription" ValueField="AccountID" />
    </DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>
```

I hope this will help you solving your issue :).

Comment: I have edited/added TreeNodeBinding for NavigateURL and sure the URL column in my DataTable for binding `<DataBindings>
                    <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="System.Data.DataRowView" 
            TextField="Name" ValueField="ID" NavigateUrlField="URL" SelectAction="Expand" Target="FrameName"/>
                </DataBindings> `